# PHP Gallery CMS - Cannot Update Row in PHPMyadmin (LONG)

Tags: php

**Project:** Create a simple CMS for a photography website. My first project in php. :)

**Problem:** I am 90% finished with the CMS, but have ran into an issue of not being able to **UPDATE** row data after being **READ** from database.

**The Goal:** What I am trying to achieve seems simple. I have an admin page that reads image data from a database (id, image) and I am using a while loop to display this. It works great, and so does the delete button.

[image]

```
 <?php

 $query = "SELECT * FROM photos";

 $select_all_photos_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_photos_query)) {

      $photos_id = $row['photos_id'];
      $photos_image = $row['photos_image'];
      $photos_title = $row['photos_title'];
      $photos_alt   = $row['photos_alt'];

      echo "<tr>

                <td><input type='checkbox' name='photo' value='photo'></td>
                <td><img src='../images/$photos_image' width='70'></td>
                <td><a class='edit' href='edit_photo.php?&p_id={$photos_id}'>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Are you sure?') \"class='delete' href='admin.php?delete={$photos_id}'>Delete</a></td>

            </tr>";

 }

 ?>
```

The problem I am having is the Edit Button in my while loop. I am using a get method in my href to get the edit_photo.php page with a parameter named "p_id" that is = to $photos_id.

Once I click the Edit button it sends me to the edit_photo.php page and I see all of the CORRECT information which tells me it is reading it correctly. I do get a error at the bottom ( Notice: Undefined variable: photos_file) See code below.

[image]

```
    <?php 

    if (isset($_GET['p_id'])) {

    $photo_id = $_GET['p_id']; 

    // Send query to photos table in database. //
    $query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE photos_id = $photo_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    // Grab unique row from photos table in database. //
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $photo_file = $row['photos_image'];
    $photos_title = $row['photos_title'];
    $photos_desc = $row['photos_alt'];

    }

    }

    ?>
```

Now. Here comes the big problem. When I try to update this information, the program busts. I even checked to see if my sql is correct, and if the queries are connecting to database. See code below.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['image'])) {

    // After "Save" is pressed, the values white space is trimmed and assigned to a variable. //
    $photos_title = trim($_POST['photos-title']);
    $photos_desc = trim($_POST['photos-description']);
    $photos_file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $photos_file_temp = $_FILES['image']['name_tmp'];

    // The new variables are sanitized. //
    $photos_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $photos_title);
    $photos_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $photos_desc);

    }

    // Send the Update query to the database. //
    $update_query = " UPDATE photos SET
              photos_image = '$photos_file', photos_title = '$photos_title', photos_alt = '$photos_desc'
              WHERE photos_id = '$photo_id' ";

    // Test the SQL syntax. // 
    if(!$update_query) {

    echo "Wrong." . " " .  mysqli_error($connection);
    }
    else { echo "The SQL appears right..." . "<br>";
    } 


    // Test the Update query. //         
    $update_result = mysqli_query($connection, $update_query);

    if(!$update_result) {
    echo "Didnt Connect." . " " .  mysqli_error($connection);
    } else {
    echo "Sent query to to database.";
    }

    ?>

    <form action="edit_photo.php" class="settings-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group edit-preview">
        <label for="image">Photo</label>
        <img src= <?php echo "../images/$photo_file"?> >
        <input type="file" name="file_upload">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photos-title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="photos-title" value= <?php echo "$photos_title" ?> class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="photos-description">Description</label>
        <textarea type="text" rows="4" name="photos-description" class="form-control" ><?php echo "$photos_desc" ?> </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="image" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Photo">
    </div>

</form>
```

I have spent four days trying to figure this out with no luck.

Comment: it's failing because of this `['name_tmp']`. The syntax is `['tmp_name']` - Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php so your temp file never gets processed.

Comment: However, I don't see a `type="file" name="image"` anywhere here, nor do I see the form that goes with the upload file.

Comment: so... have I fallen onto deaf ears here? where are we with the comments I left?

Comment: Fred - Thank you. I have added the html form I am using to try and update the row.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my answer.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and "protecting" your delete link with a JS confirmation is useless. JS-disabled clients (especially spiders/pre-fetchers) will ignore it and hit your delete link, and now you've nuked everything. Read this: http://www.thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom

Comment: @MarcB As Wile E. would have his *Yipes!* sign while going down... Good point on that (JS)

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, it's failing because of this `['name_tmp']`.

The syntax is `['tmp_name']` - you had those inversed

- Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php so your temp file never gets processed.

Then as per your edit and seeing your HTML form:

You're using `name="file_upload"` and then using the `$_FILES['image']` array; those names need to match.

Error reporting would have helped you here.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Additional note.**

If you are attempting to set the given (file) column as binary data instead of the path to the given file(s) as text, then you MUST escape it.

Otherwise, MySQL will throw you an error.

If that is the case, you will need to do the same as the others:

```
$photos_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['name']; // notice I changed it to what it should be
$photos_file = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $photos_file);
```

as per `<input type="file" name="file_upload">`

---

Check for errors against all your queries; you're not doing that in your `$query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE photos_id = $photo_id";` query.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to all `mysqli_query()` should there be an error somewhere.

---

**HTML stickler.**

`<textarea type="text"` - `<textarea>` does not have a "text" type; remove it.

---

**Footnotes.**

If you want to check if your UPDATE truly was successful, use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Instead of `else { echo "The SQL appears right..." . "<br>"; }`

---

As outlined in comments, your code is open an SQL injection.

If `$photo_id` is an integer, change

```
$photo_id = $_GET['p_id'];
```

to

```
$photo_id = (int)$_GET['p_id'];
```

However, if that is a string, then you will need to quote it and escape it in your query.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments Frank. This is a lot to take in for a newbie. 
I am going to try and make these edits/suggestions and see if i cant find the problem.

Comment: @LesTaylor You're welcome Les. Yeah I know and updating a db can be quite tricky. There is one thing though that I'm unsure about and it's this `<input type='checkbox' name='photo' value='photo'>` where in all of that, there isn't `<form>` tags. TBH, I'm not sure if by not having them, if it's also playing a role in all this. Check for errors again and view your HTML source to see what's in there. It's just as good a tool for coders and will help you, I'm sure. As would doing `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to see what's set or not. I made a few edits, but not sure if I'd be of anymore help.